# Update ansible (ubuntu server 14)

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ansible

I installed ansible in Ubunru server 14 using this tutorial http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-apt-ubuntu

After I checked version of ansible:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 1.5.5
```

But I need 1.9. How to update it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you installed it correctly? The version in the PPA for 14.04 is 1.9.4-1, so I don't know where 1.5.5 would be coming from.

In any case, you could try erasing ansible (`sudo apititude erase ansible` should work), and installing ansible with pip as per http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-pip

(Namely, have pip installed, then run `pip install --upgrade ansible`)

Answer (score 38):

From Ansible website:

1) First remove installed version of ansible using    `sudo apt-get remove --purge ansible`

2) Now add the correct ppa using `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible`

3) Update the package list: `sudo apt-get update`

4) Install ansible: `sudo apt-get install ansible`

I had the same issues as you. Above steps worked like a charm :)

Comment: The steps work like a charm. On Ubunty 14.04, with the above steps,  Ansible 2.3.0.0 installed perfectly fine.

Comment: This worked but I don't understand what this really does. I checked my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ansible-ansible-xenial.list` before and after and it didn't change. Why does running `apt-get install --only-upgrade ansible` not work but this does?